# How to show powerpoint in iframe

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, iframe, powerpoint

I am able to show pdf in the iframe but ppt is not loading in the iframe. It is opening as a new window. I need to show it inline. Is there any specific parameters for ppt ?

Answer (score 1):

The best way I can think of is to convert your powerpoint file to Flash.

That way you can easily add it to your webpage, iframe or whatever you like.

Here is a link to some free software that you can use to convert your powerpoint presentations.

[Link to Powerpoint to Flash Convertor](http://www.authorgen.com/authorpoint-lite-free/powerpoint-to-flash-converter.aspx)

In case you want to still use powerpoint files on your webpage, check out this page for full explanation and directions.

[Putting your Powerpoint on the web](http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00708.htm)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I wanted to keep the file as is . Is there any way to load it directly to the webpage ?

Comment: Please check my answer. I've made some additions.

Comment: Flash isn't the recommended way anymore: https://redmondmag.com/articles/2017/07/25/adobe-ending-flash-support.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[Google Docs Viewer](http://docs.google.com/viewer) is a version of Google Docs that supports being included via iframe, and it supports viewing Powerpoint Presentations.

Comment: I actually want to show the document in an iframe in my website.

Answer (score 0):

You can share it if you upload it to [Skydrive](http://office.live.com/), set the share permissions to Everyone and get the Embed code. Note that this is just another way of converting it to HTML.

Comment: thanks ! Is there a way to convert to html from the code. I have the code which converts the ppt to byte stream. could i convert to html from the stream ?

Comment: I don't think this is applicable to automation unless there is some sort of upload API for Skydrive (there may be but I don't know the service well enough to be able to answer that.)